# Storing HashMap<String, Bitmap> in ArrayList - can't decode Bitmaps upon displaying

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap

I have an ArrayList which stores a HashMap of Bitmaps, but when I try to display them with ListView adapter it shows this error(and yes I am absolutely sure that Uri is correct and links to an image):

```
08-01 14:03:53.103: E/BitmapFactory(7225): Unable to decode stream:        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@656c2d18: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-01 14:03:53.103: I/System.out(7225): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@656c2d18
```

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> imgList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>();

for(int i = 0; i < jData.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jData.getJSONObject(i);

//get the imageURL and set it to string
JSONObject images = c.getJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES);
JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(TAG_THUMBNAIL);
String imageURL = thumbnail.getString(TAG_URL);

//Decode Bitmap before putting in HashMap

try {
                            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//create new HashMap
HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmap=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
//put HashMap in the ArrayList
bitmap.put(TAG_PIC, pic);
imgList.add(bitmap);

 }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
return null;
        }

// and finally display them in ImageView

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ActivityMain.this, imgList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PIC },
                new int[] { R.id.ivThumb 
                         });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

I have also tried using for loop to go through all of the lv items and setting imageViews but it using this code it only sets the ImageView of the first item (but loops through all images)

```
     for(childIndex = 0; childIndex < lv.getAdapter().getCount(); childIndex++) {

                    //     lv.setSelection(childIndex);



                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            //  childView = lv.getChildAt(childIndex);
                                //lv.setSelection(childIndex);
                                iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumb);
                                iv.setImageBitmap(pic);
                            }
                       });                              
                    }
```

So if you could help me do this rather simple but a little confusing thing, it would be great! (I would prefer using hashmap, because it is easier for me to understand, but any way that works will be great!)

EDIT: Added FOR loop and corrected HashMap statement placement.

Comment: Are you creating a new HashMap for each image, to be added to the imgList as the next list element? I ask because the loop for filling the imgList isn't shown.

Comment: Sorry for that - yes, I am creating a new HashMap everytime.

Comment: So why is the `HashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmap=new HashMap<>();` not right in front of `bitmap.put(TAG_PIC, pic);` - the only "good" place for that statement?

Comment: I thought you would ask that.. In code it is where it should be, while making this post I made a small mistake and copied it to wrong place. Made an EDIT to the post so it doesn't confuse anyone anymore. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It crashes in decodeStream and it says that it's unable to open file. If you sure that uri is correct that I recomend you to save input stream somewhere on SD card and try to open saved file with image viewer. It might be that image stream is broken and BitmapFactory unable to decode it.

Comment: Yes I am 100% positive that uri is correct, because in single item view everything works with same uri's (hashmap not needed).